# Getting update statement set right MySQL based on my Select statement

Tags: mysql, sql-update

Ive got an error in my database, and need to mass correct some bits... but its not going to be easy.. or so I think!? Im not fantastic at SQL statements.. mostly over ever used them for pulling data out, rather than mass putting data in. So I want to be sure Im getting my statement correct before I make a real mess of things. Heres my query...

```
    SELECT * FROM tickets_messages
    INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets_messages.ticket_id = tickets.id 
    INNER JOIN people ON tickets_messages.person_id = people.id
    WHERE tickets.person_id = 201 AND tickets_messages.person_id = 32
```

We have "tickets" in the system, linked by two tables People and tickets_messages. Some messages need to be under id 32.. and some under id 201, which is why I have performed an inner join to find tickets that the system thinks are owned by 201.. but actually show up in the tickets_messages as being 32.

In short, I want to change my select statement, with the inner join, to an update statement. Anyone any suggestions on doing that.. as Im feeling a little shakey on this area.

P.S. This is my guess.. is is correct:

```
   UPDATE tickets_messages SET person_id = 201 
   INNER JOIN tickets ON tickets_messages.ticket_id = tickets.id 
   INNER JOIN people ON tickets_messages.person_id = people.id
   WHERE tickets.person_id = 201 AND tickets_messages.person_id = 32
```

Thanks

Comment: You can always compare the selected records with the updated records and see at least if the quantity is the same. But this would have to to be made within a transaction context to avoid updating wrong data.

Answer (score 0):

What's your question? Do you just want someone to confirm that the UPDATE command will do what you want? If the goal is to set `ticket_messages.person_id` to 201 in all the records found by the SELECT query, then it looks right to me.

Comment: Hi, as its a big update Im applying... and Im not 100% on inner joins with updates, yes I was hoping someone might look and see if my query appears correct.